# Django Queryset - filter "before end date" if existing

Tags: django, date, django-queryset, django-south

I have model that use to don't have DateField, now I'm migrating it with "south"; and I'm adding a "start_date" and "end_date" to it:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_attribute = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    start_date = models.DateField(default = date.today)#Newly added field
    end_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)#Newly added field
```

For the existing records on the database (and the future ones) the start_date will be by default set to today's date, the old records will not have an end_date, and future ones may have a blank end_date if not specified.

My need: Given a DATE:

- Filter objects from DB, that DATE is between start_date and end_date if the object has both start and end date (e.g: `MyModel.objects.filter(start_date__lte=DATE, end_date__gte=DATE`)
- Filter objects from DB, that DATE is newer than start_date if the object has blank (or null) end_date

Is my migration correct ?

Which queryset should I perfprm to accomplish my need.

Comment: I'm trying with Q complexe lookup https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects; I will tell you when I'm done..

Comment: @GwynBleidD   MyModel.objects.filter((Q(start_date__lte=today) & (Q(end_date__isnull=True) | Q(end_date__gte=end))))